# Can a glass stovetop be used for both meat and milk?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul, meat-and-milk

Is it permissible to use a glass stovetop for both meat and milk? Or is it forbidden? A OK article says that one should not use a glass stove top for meat and milk, however rabbikaganoff Is My Stove Kosher article makes no distinction between a regular and glass electric stove.

If this is accidently done, would the pot require kashering, since poskim are lenient after the fact?

Sources are much appreciated.

Comment: [1] https://ohr.edu/5167

Comment: [2] Yoreh Deah 92:5 to 6 Yorey Deah 92:7 might undermine the reasoning given above, I'm not sure.

Comment: As it appears to me, it seems it would be forbidden before the fact but permitted only after the fact. As if the stovetop is clean and dry, all is permitted after the fact [1]. And if some contents of the pot spill over and touch the glass surface and then touch the pot, it would be nullified 60:1 (unless a large ammount spilt over)and the drop that touches the pot, only touches the part of the pot closest to the heat source..[2]

Comment: Stovetops are generally considered treif anyway, but the part where the pot touches is regularly kashered by way of fire. Glass stovetops pose a unique issue with this solution by virtue of there not being any fire, even though there is heat. I’m curious to see how this is resolved. The fancy electromagnetic induction stoves are even worse - they heat up the contents of the pot without heating up the stove itself.

Comment: I asked my rabbi this question. He said that if a very small drop falls on the glass stovetop, where ot ISN'T hot, and the proceeds to spread out and touch near the base of the pot, the surface area and thickness aren't sufficient enough to transfer flavours. A larger drop is a very different story.

Comment: @DonielF, I my rabbi Yoreh Deah 95:2 and I was told, by him, that the Remas gloss doesn't apply to extremely small amounts of liquid/food.

Comment: Remember that MY is a resource, not a Rabbi. Your Rabbi should be the only authority you ask for practical halachic queries.

Comment: @DonielF, I meant to say:

Comment: I SHOWED my rabbi